# Repeating numbers with modulo -1 to 1 using positive and negative numbers

Tags: sequence, octave, modulo

Repeating numbers with modulo

I know I can "wrap" / loop numbers back onto themselves like **2,3,1,2,3,1,...**
by using modulo.

Example code below.

```
a=[1:8]'
b=mod(a,3)+1
```

But how can I use modulo to "wrap" numbers back onto themselves from -1 to 1  (-1,-.5,0,.5,1).  **Some test numbers would be a=[1.1,-2.3,.3,-.5] it would loop around and the values would be between -1 to 1**.

I guess a visual example would be bending an x,y plane from -1 to 1 into a torus (how it loops back onto itself).

[image: Loop onto itself]

I was thinking of how a sin wave goes 0,1,0,-1 and back again but I wasn't sure how I could implement it.

PS: I'm using Octave 4.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by offsetting the value before taking the modulo, then reversing the offset after.

For example, if the target range is [*a*,*b*) (the half-open interval such that *b* is not part of the interval), then one can do:

```
y = mod( x - a, b - a ) + a;
```

For example:

```
a = -1;
b = 1;
x = -10:0.01:10;
y = mod( x - a, b - a ) + a;
plot(x,y)
```